# Sketch the image under the function $w = \log z$ of the following set $\{z : Im z > 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, mobius-transformation

I would love some help with this question please:

**Sketch the image under the function $w = \log z$ of the following set  $\{z : Im z > 0\}$**

What I have done so far is as follows:

$R= \{x+iy: y>0, x \in {\bf R}\}$

$R= \{re^{iθ}: 0<θ\le \pi,r>0\}$

$f(R)= \{~\log re^{iθ}:  0<θ\le \pi,r>0,\}$

$=\{\log r + iθ:  0<θ\le \pi,r>0\}$

I am unsure if this is correct and if it correct would the sketch be all the area above the x axis from $0$ to $\pi$?

Also would the sketch exclude the origin since $\log(0)$ is not defined and would it also exclude the line of the x-axis since $θ>0$?

I hope that my question is clear and I would really love any help on this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Seems right https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#The_complex_logarithm_as_a_conformal_map